# Error while doing gzip in linux

Tags: linux

I have some files in a Linux local directory . I would like merge all files in this directory to a single file and I want that single file to be gzipped

```
[omega@node10 sample_input_files]$ pwd
/dev/omega/sample_input_files
[omega@node10 sample_input_files]$ ls -ltr
total 16
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 omega cldusers    9 Nov 28 17:07 a1.txt
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 omega cldusers    7 Nov 28 17:07 a2.txt
[omega@node10 sample_input_files]$
```

I tried the below  and it works

```
 cat a*.txt >> result.txt
```

But when I try the below command I get error

```
 cat a*.txt >> gzip result.txt

 cat: result.txt: No such file or directory
```

I want to store result.txt.gz in the same location . How do I do that ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` and `>>` is for writing to files. To pass the data to a command, use a pipe `|`:

```
cat a*.txt | gzip > result.txt.gz
```

Comment: If I unzip the result I am expecting it to be result.txt

Comment: If you unzip it with `gzip -d result.txt.gz` you will get a file `result.txt`